What is the space complexity of the following code?
What is the space complexity of the following code?
def f(n):
    sum = 0
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            sum = sum + f(i)
    return sum

So, this is a recursive function and I thought since every function is calling all the functions below it, the space complexity would be O(n!) since the stack would maintain all the function calls. But the correct answer is O(n). Can someone please explain in detail?

To determine the space complexity of this code, let's analyze the memory usage.
The code defines a function f(n) which recursively calls itself n times. In each recursive call, a variable sum is created to store the sum of the results from the recursive calls.
Since the recursive calls are nested, there will be multiple instances of the sum variable created. The number of instances depends on the depth of the recursion, which is dictated by the input n.
Let's break down the space complexity:

The space required for each instance of the sum variable is constant, regardless of the input size n.
The maximum depth of the recursion is n, meaning there can be at most n instances of the sum variable at any given time during the execution of the code.

Therefore, the space complexity of the code is O(n), as the space required scales linearly with the input size n.

@StephenC: No, this function isn’t tail-recursive.
